# Spring task scheduler delay from jndi

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, jndi

I'm configuring a Spring task scheduler.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="servicesConfigurationBean" method="loadResources" fixed-delay="300000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

It's working properly. Now I would like to set the delay value from a JNDI lookup. So I tried the following:

```
<task:scheduled ref="servicesConfigurationBean" method="loadResources">
    <property name="fixed-delay"><ref local="servicesRefreshRate"/></property>
</task:scheduled>
```

But now I obtain the following exception:

> [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'task:scheduled' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.[/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'task:scheduled' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

I understand the cause of the exception, so, is there a viable solution to my problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<property>` won't work, because `<task:scheduled>` is a macro, not a bean definition. The two work very differently.

Try using Spring-EL instead:

```
<task:scheduled ref="servicesConfigurationBean" 
                method="loadResources" 
                fixed-delay="#servicesRefreshRate" />
```

I haven't tried it, but give it a go.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the SpEL, but it was exactlye what I was looking for. Now it's time for some due RTFM. :)